# wordpress не работает pattern и required в input добавленном на страницу общих настроек

Tags: wordpress

Доброго времени суток. Добавляю на страницу общих настроек дополнительные поля. См. картинку. Делаю первый и второй телефон обязательными с помощью `required`, и прописываю `pattern`, однако валидация не срабатывает, можно поставить любые значения. Как можно это исправить?

```
function show_field_tel($number) { ?>
        <input
            name="tel_<?php echo $number?>"
            size="30"
            type="tel"
            placeholder="+7 (900) 123-45-67"
            <?php if ($number === 1 || $number === 2) echo 'required'?>
            pattern="\+7\s?[\(]{0,1}9[0-9]{2}[\)]{0,1}\s?((\d{3}[-]{0,1}\d{2}[-]{0,1}\d{2})|(\d{2}[-]{0,1}\d{3}[-]{0,1}\d{2}))"
            value="<?php echo get_option( "tel_$number" )?>"
        /><?php
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Формы с опциями в админке WordPress строятся в режиме без валидации. Посмотрите на html код, и вы увидите нечто вроде

```
<form method="post" action="options.php" novalidate="novalidate" _lpchecked="1">
```

Валидация полей формы с поциями должна проводиться с помощью обратного вызова `sanitize_callback`. Подробнее об этом можно почитать на русском [здесь](https://wp-kama.ru/id_3773/api-optsiy-nastroek.html).

Comment: Спасибо большое!